# Change SPO Library Command Bar JSON when single document is selected

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I am trying to edit a SPO Library Command Bar using JSON, specifically when a single document is selected via the dot at the left. When I select a doc, the command bar changes. I then try to edit the JSON, but it does not change the "selected" single doc view.

My JSON is mostly hiding command bar elements and moving others to be in position 1, 2, etc.

What is the secret to changing the command bar when a document is selected?

Comment: What changes you need in command bar when document is selected?

Comment: Hi Ganesh!  Specifically, I need 'properties' far at the left next to Edit in grid view, not inside of the 3 dot drop-down

Comment: Ganesh, I really need to know how to make command bar changes the single-document-selected command bar arrangement vs the no-documents-selected command bar arrangement. I can't figure how to differentiate between the two.  Thank you!

Comment: Ideally, this should work `{
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "properties",
        "position": 1,
        "selectionModes": [
          "SingleSelection"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}`. Can you check if it works at your end? If not, raise a support ticket with Microsoft as this maybe bug in funcationality: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support

Comment: Ganesh, This works perfectly AND once again you taught me more about SharePoint and custom code!  Thank you

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this, it should work for you:

```
{
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "properties",
        "position": 1,
        "selectionModes": [
          "SingleSelection"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can adjust the SharePoint JSON based on `selectionModes` property for single selection or multiple selection of documents inside document library.

The value of this property can be array of strings where the following strings are allowed:

- NoSelection
- SingleSelection
- MultiSelection